# Generation has thrown an Exception: float division by zero (rigtify)

Tags: rigging, rigify

So I am trying to follow this tutorial from bran scuplts and when I try to generate the rig. It kept tell me this error.

Here the link to my file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/149thMAvbUwJR42KUpyiiPDl5e79EttL2/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: It sounds as if there is a bug in Rigify in which case you will have to report it to the developers via Blender's Help > Report a Bug menu as there are no Blender developers here. (I can confirm that I get the same error here using Blender 4.02.)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.